Plot 3D does not produce a uniform red colored surface
R1[x_, t_] = -((t^41 x^2)/33452526613163807108170062053440751665152000000000);

   pic1 = Plot3D[Abs[R1[x, t]], {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> Full, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "t"}, AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 14], 
  BoxStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black, 16], 
  BoxRatios -> {1.5, 1.5, 1.5}, ViewPoint -> {-2, -2, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]


  pic2 = Plot3D[Abs[R1[x, t]], {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {"x", "t"}, 
      AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}}, 
      LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 14], 
      BoxStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black, 16], 
      BoxRatios -> {1.5, 1.5, 1.5}, ViewPoint -> {-2, -2, 1}, 
      PlotStyle -> Red]


pic2 is rendered with a uniform Red colored surface but pic1 is not. The only difference between two codes is the domain: 0<x,t<5 vs 0<x,t<10. How can a uniform color be obtained for pic1 similar to pic2?

Add Lighting:
pic1 = Plot3D[Abs[R1[x, t]], {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> Full, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "t"}, AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 14], 
  BoxStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black, 16], 
  BoxRatios -> {1.5, 1.5, 1.5}, ViewPoint -> {-2, -2, 1}
  , PlotStyle -> Red
  , Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}
  ]

